# iterating through the rows of a table using tableadapters in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, tableadapter

i have a problem. I have database with a tableadpater. i want to get the userid with this tableadapter.

```
 Dim dsGN As New ForumTableAdapters.Message2TableAdapter

    Dim dtBetrieb As Data.DataTable = dsGN.GetUserIdFromThisMessage(ConversationID)

    For Each objRow As dsGN.Message2Row In dtBetrieb.Rows

        mystring = objRow.UserId.ToString
    Next
```

i get the error "dsGN.Message2Row is not defined"

The Name ob my table in the database is "Message"
i hope that somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this :

```
GridView.DataSource = yourAdapter.GetUserID(ID);
GridView.DataBind();
```

Then make a tableadapter named:GetUserID where you select from your tables passing the ID like: @ID;

Hope this helped!
You can read more about this here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581776.aspx